# How to connect the session which has some proxy setting as pre requisites in robot framework

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

In my project i need to open session and perform some action in the session.
As pre requesities,to open that session in putty we need to set proxy hostname(127.0.0.1) and port(1080) in SockS5 under proxy type in proxy under connections.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, SSHLibrary does not support SOCKS5 protocol according to this [open issue](https://github.com/robotframework/SSHLibrary/issues/328).

However, you can always call the below command from robot framework using Process if you insist.

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='nc --proxy-type socks4 --proxy 127.0.0.1:9050 %h %p' user@host
```